# Python debuggers not stepping into a coroutine?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-asyncio, ipdb

In the example below:

```
import asyncio
import ipdb

class EchoServerProtocol:
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Received %r from %s' % (message, addr))
        print('Send %r to %s' % (message, addr))
        self.transport.sendto(data, addr)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ipdb.set_trace(context=21)
print("Starting UDP server")
# One protocol instance will be created to serve all client requests
listen = loop.create_datagram_endpoint(    EchoServerProtocol, local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))
transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(listen)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

transport.close()
loop.close()
```

I'm trying to step into the

`loop.create_datagram_endpoint(    EchoServerProtocol, local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))`

to understand how it behaves internally.
However when I try to step into the coroutine, the debugger just jumps over it as if `n` has been pressed instead of `s`.

```
> ../async_test.py(18)<module>()
     17 # One protocol instance will be created to serve all client requests
---> 18 listen = loop.create_datagram_endpoint(    EchoServerProtocol, local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))
     19 transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(listen)

ipdb> s
> ../async_test.py(19)<module>()
     18 listen = loop.create_datagram_endpoint(    EchoServerProtocol, local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))
---> 19 transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(listen)
     20 

ipdb>
```

The behavior is experienced with PyCharm (2016 2.3 Community)  IDE.

I would expect to end [here](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/f060dff83b3e9505091fc88e80b7be3bc1671e40/asyncio/base_events.py#L751) and be able to step additionally through the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you call `await` or `yield from` for your coroutine like

```
listen = await loop.create_datagram_endpoint(EchoServerProtocol, 
                                             local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))
```

In your example `listen` is not a result of coroutine execution but **coroutine instance** itself.
Actual execution is performed by next line: `loop.run_until_complete()`.